# I want A Quartz That Execute On Every month of 1st day?

Tags: task, scheduler, quartz.net, crontrigger

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                       .StartAt(DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(1))
                          .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                           .StartNow()
                          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                              .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
                          .WithRepeatCount(0)
                            )
                      .Build();
```

I want Trigger That Execute on Every month OF 1st day

Answer (score 5):

You've got two options there. You can use a cron expression and use `WithCronSchedule` in your trigger using this cron expression:

> 0 0 12 1 1/1 ? *

this is the code:

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .Create()
    .StartNow()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "myGroup")
    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 1 1/1 ? *")
    .Build();
```

*Notice this trigger would start at midday.*

You can check the cron expression and customize it using this helpful [tool](http://www.cronmaker.com/).

Option 2 is a schedule using `CronScheduleBuilder.MonthlyOnDayAndHourAndMinute`:

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .Create()
    .StartNow()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "myGroup")
    .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.MonthlyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(1, 12, 0))
    .Build();
```

**NOTES:**

Cron expressions in Quartz.Net are made up of 7 [sub-expressions](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html):

```
1. Seconds
2. Minutes
3. Hours
4. Day-of-Month
5. Month
6. Day-of-Week
7. Year (optional field)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to execute on the first weekday of the month this in a java quartz CronTrigger and ended up on this page. Not sure if this works with Quartz.Net, but java quartz supports the notation `0 7 1 1W * ?` for first weekday of the month. I'm writing it down here for future me.

`0 7 1 1W * ?`:

- Seconds `0`
- Minutes `7`
- Hours `1`
- Day-of-month `1W` weekday nearest the first of the month
- Month `*`
- Day-of-Week `?` no specific value

Also see the [javadoc of org.quartz.CronExpression](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html).